# how to create ProgressBar for DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

i have a DataGridView in which i am loading the data. when i load it take long time.

i would like to get information of of progress by using progress bar.

i got one ProgressBar called "progressBar1" and "timer1"

the following code to fetch data into grid.

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = totalValues;
//progressBar1
//timer1
```

tried lot to search on net and trying from last 7 hours but could not succeeded.. please help me
thanks for the help.

Comment: It sounds like you've already created a `ProgressBar`.  What is your actual question?  How to tie events from the data source to update the progress of the bar?  How to calculate the amount of time a given process will take?

Comment: Have you considered filling it manually ?

Comment: no there is loop adding value to the datagridview

Answer (score 0):

As all the progress bars goes with javascript and ajax the easiest way is to fill the content of this gridview with updatepanel(which you can find it in toolbox) and you can have your progress bar in updateprogress(again you can find this in toolbox and you can use a note or a flash picture for waiting)....let me know if you encountered any problem with working with them